# Bounded superposition operator in the space of bounded variation functions

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation, unbounded-operators

For $n\in\mathbb N$ put $A_n:=\{k/2^n\ |\ k\in\{1,\ldots,2^n-1\}\}$. Consider $g:[0,1]\times\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, defined by
    \begin{align*}
  g(t,u)=
  \begin{cases}
   2^{-n}\chi_{A_n}(t) & \text{for }u=2^{-n},n\in\mathbb N, \\
   0 & \text{otherwise},
  \end{cases}
 \end{align*}
where $\chi_A$ denotes the characteristic function of a set $A$, i.e $\chi_A(t)=1$ if $t\in A$ and 0 elsewhere.

This means that $g$ is zero everywhere except at the points $(k/2^n,1/2^n)$ for $k=1,\ldots,2^n-1$ where it is $1/2^n$.

> *I would now like to prove (or disprove) the following: For each $r>0$ there is some $M_r>0$ such that for each partition $0=t_0<\ldots<t_p=1$ ($p\in\mathbb N$) of $[0,1]$ and all $u_0,\ldots,u_p\in\mathbb R$ with $\sum_{j=1}^p|u_{j-1}-u_j|\leq r$ we have
>   \begin{align}
> \sum_{j=0}^p|g(t_j,u_j)|\leq M_r.\tag{1}
> \end{align}*

I only know that if $t_j=j/2^m$ and $u_j=1/2^m$ for all $j$ and some fixed $m\in\mathbb N$,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=0}^{2^m-1}|g(t_j,u_j)|=\frac{2^m-1}{2^m},
\end{align*}
and if on the other hand the $u_j$ jump up and down, i.e. $u_j=denom(j/2^m)$, where $denom$ gives the denominator of the reduced fraction $j/2^m$ (for instance, $denom(6/8)=denom(3/4)=4$) then (1) with $p=2^m$ is $m/2$ and so increases for $m\to\infty$. However, in this case, the variation of the $u_j$ also increases for $m\to\infty$.

The overall idea shall be to show that if $x:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ is a function of bounded variation with $Var(x)\leq r$, then $Var(g(\cdot,x(\cdot)))\leq 4M_r$, but I was not able to wrap my head around it so far.

Any ideas are highly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Actually under your condition we have $$\sum_{j=0}^n|g(t_j,u_j)|={n-1\over 2^n}\ne {2^n-1\over 2^n}$$

Comment: Yes, you are right, thank you! The upper bound should be $2^n-1$. I edited the question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your remarks, I agree! I edited the question.

Comment: I am unsure whether the number $n$ is supposed to be fixed or whether you want to find $M_r>0$ which works for all $n$. Or is the $n$ in the partition a different $n$ than the one in the definition of $g$ (then please use $\tilde n$ or something)?
Otherwise the question is nearly trivial, since $g$ is bounded by $1/2^n$: By choosing $M_r=1$ (independent of $r$), you obtain
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^n|g(t_j,u_j)|
\le
\sum_{j=0}^n
2^{-n}
=
(n+1)2^{-n}
\leq M_r.
\end{align}
Also, are the $u_j$ supposed to be distinct or can they be all the same? Please clarify!

Comment: Thank you for your question. The $u_j$ can be arbitrary as long as they meet the variation condition. Thus, they all can be identical, as they are in my first example $(u_j=1/2^m)$. Moreover, $n$ is not fixed. I edited (1).

Comment: Thanks! I tried to answer the most general version of your question.

Comment: @sranthrop can you please state the source of this question, for more context?

Comment: The source is my own research :) I tried to construct a noncompact but bounded superposition operator $N_gx(t)=g(t,x(t))$ in the space $BV$ of functions of bounded variation, where the set of points at which $g$ is not zero is countable. Here, $BV$ is equipped with the norm $||x||_{BV}=\sup_{0\leq t\leq 1}|x(t)|+Var(x)$.
The above operator is not compact, because the functions $x_n(t)=1/2^n$ form a bounded sequence in $BV$, but $y_n(t)=g(t,x_n(t))=\chi_{A_n}(t)/2^n$ cannot have a convergent subsequence in $BV$, because it converges to zero, yet its variation is bounded away from 0.

Comment: EDIT: I tried to construct a noncompact but bounded superposition operator Ngx(t)=g(t,x(t)) in the space BV of functions of bounded variation, where the set of $t\in[0,1]$ at which $g(t,u)$ is not zero is countable for each fixed $u\in\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I claim that $M_r = 2r+1$ does the trick.

Denote $T=(t_0,\dots,t_p)$, $U=(u_0,\dots,u_p)$, $\|U\|= \sum_{j=1}^p|u_{j-1}-u_j|$ and $G(U) = \sum_{j=0}^p|g(t_j,u_j)|$. We have to prove that $G(U) \le 2\|U\|+1$ for all possible $U$. Here is a visualization (the values in the middle are the non-zero values of $g$):

[image]

If we stay in one layer over a period $\Delta t$, then $G(U)$ increases at most by $\Delta t$. Therefore, staying in one layer for the whole time yields $G(U)\le 1$ and $\|U\|=0$.

If we switch into some layer $k$ (over a time period $\Delta t$), we gain (compared to staying in the previous layer) at most $\Delta G = \frac{1}{2^k}$, which is the value of $g$ in the $k$-th layer, while paying the prize of at least $\Delta\|U\| = \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$, which is the minimal distance from layer $k$ to another layer.

Therefore the ratio is at most $2$, since
$$
\frac{\Delta G }{\Delta\|U\|} \le 2
$$
These considerations imply $G(U) \le 1 + 2\|U\|$ for all possible $U$.

*Remark:* $M_r = 2r+1$ is probably not a tight bound.

Comment: Unfortunately, your statements is not more complicated than mine. The point is that if the $u_j$ jump between two numbers $1/2^n$ and $1/2^m$, then the number of admissible $t$'s for which my $g$ is not zero my increase. In your statement, $n$ is fixed, and so this problem cannot occur.

Comment: @sranthrop You are right, of course, my bad! Your question was much harder than expected, but I think I found a solution. I edited my answer accordingly (I basically had to rewrite it completely). Hope this helps..

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Although it is not as rigorous as I hoped, it gave me the main ideas I needed to complete this problem. Thank you!

Comment: I agree that it is not rigorous enough in this form. I'm glad it helped!